# Infragistics WebHierarchicalDataGrid looses bottom most row formatiing when a detail row is expanded

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

Hi I am using a Infragistics 15.1 `WebHierarchicalDataGrid` in my ASPX page.

The grid has no vertical scrollbar(this is how my client wants). So when I expand any detail row, grid has to expand it's current height which is when it looses it formatting on the bottom rows. For instance if the detail row has height of 30px, 3 rows will loose formatting(assuming each row height is 10 px)

I have tried few settings

```
<Behaviors>
           <ig:ColumnFixing Enabled="true" ShowFixButtons="false" ></ig:ColumnFixing>
```

and enabled the footer (This helps only one row line).

None of it helped. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set the WHDG Height? If yes is it set in percent?

Comment: @KonstantinDinev No there is no fixed height on this grid, my client does not wants that. FYI, if I set the height of grid to say 400px, then there is no loss of formatting.

Comment: Yes, I was going to advise fixing the height as this makes formatting of header and footer elements a lot more deterministic and stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply some fixed height to your `WebHierarchicalDataGrid`:

```
<ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid Height="650px">

</ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid>
```

This will make the formatting issues go away as header and footer formatting is performed based on height and width of the grid.

Comment: As I already mentioned that I can't put a fixed width to my grid as per my requirements. It has to be scroll-able only at the browser window.

Comment: Did you also try not defining a height at all?

Comment: yep. I did the workaround to get things going. I added a slider delay while opening the detail row that somehow fixed the formatting but is causing me .1sec unnecessary delay.

Comment: <ExpandCollapseAnimation SlideOpenDirection="Auto" SlideOpenDuration="100" SlideCloseDirection="Auto"
                                            SlideCloseDuration="100" />

Comment: @Chunkey If you set it to lower amount than 100 ms. then are you still seeing the issue?

Comment: I started from 0 and incremented by 10 and at 100 it stopped missing format.